# RedirectResult to Shared View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am overriding the authorize attribute and I was wondering if I could redirect the user to a shared error view via RedirectResult?

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    // if failed
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Shared/NotAuthorized.cshtml");

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

}
```

Or do I have to create an Error controller?  How do I write the string url so that it works when testing locally and published to a web server?

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate this in it's own attribute like this

```
public class HandleUnauthorizedAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() != typeof (SecurityException)) return;

        var controllerName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "Unauthorized",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
}
```

because authorization is going to throw a SecurityException if the authorization fails.

Then just register this in the global handlers.  No controller is necessary.

If you don't want to go the separate attribute route, you can always lift the filterContext.Result code out and paste it into your OnAuthorize() method.